# Substract month from date using PIG

Tags: apache-pig

How to substract month from date in PIG?

Maybe there exists some function like substractMonth('2015-03-01', 2) that will return '2015-01-01'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [SubtractDuration](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#subtract-duration):

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE ToString(SubtractDuration(ToDate('2015-03-01', 'YYYY-MM-dd'), 'P2M'), 'YYYY-MM-dd');
```

You need to convert the string containing the date to a DatetimeObject.